# Using mlt framework to export flac file play time error

Tags: flac, mlt

I use the mlt framework to convert aac to flac files,and the code as follows:
'''

```
consumer.set("acodec", "flac");
consumer.set("ab","1030k");
consumer.set("ar",44100);
consumer.set("channels",2);
```

'''
but the time of flac file is wrong.

Comment: One more params was added. consumer.set("video_off",1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. add a code follows:

```
consumer.set("f","matroska");
```

and output file's time is normal